# Need to result of column based on available column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having one view which is returning the following result:

[image]

I need to put identifier just like below image

Required output:

[image]

Explanation of Output:  If you can see the image 1 and in that image release 1 has 3 dates. From that I need to get 1 as an identifier for the MAX(IMPL_DATE).In RELEASE_ID = 1, We are having  08/20/2016, 08/09/2016 and 10/31/2016. From This 10/31/2016 is the largest date. So, Need Identifier as 1 and other 2 are going to be 0. Same thing with the RELEASE_ID 2 we have 2 dates and from them 01/13/2017 is the largest date so, need 1 in that row and other's going to be 0.

Thanks In advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when rank() over (partition by portfolio_id, release_id
                               order by impl_date desc
                              ) = 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as indentifier
from t;
```

The above will assign "1" to all rows with the maximum date.  If you want to ensure that only one row is assigned a value (even when there are ties), then use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Gordon Linoff